# ng-repeat in table , multi-level json data

Tags: json, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some table html and having trouble ng-repeating from json data with multiple levels.

I have the TR working, creating a list of employee names each in a TD, however I cannot make the second TD repeat for each Timestamp in each first row of absence which should create 7 TDs.

Any idea what might I be doing wrong?

Output I would like to have:

```
| DisplayName | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

staff-calendar-table-row.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in d.Employee">
  <td>{{row.Details.DisplayName}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="absence in row.Absence[0].Timestamp">cell - {{$index}}</td>
</tr>
```

Json Data:

```
{
  "d": {
    "__type": "IntegratedCalendarDetails:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
    "Employee": [{
        "__type": "Employee:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
        "Absence": [{
            "__type": "Absence:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
            "Timestamp": ["\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(1443650400000+0200)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"],
            "Type": "Vacation Leave"
          }
        ],
        "Details": {
          "__type": "User:#Common.Entities",
          "DisplayName": "Alan"
        }
      }, {
        "__type": "Employee:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
        "Absence": [{
            "__type": "Absence:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
            "Timestamp": ["\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(1443477600000+0200)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"],
            "Type": "Other Leave"
          }
        ],
        "Details": {
          "__type": "User:#Common.Entities",
          "DisplayName": "Alistair"
        }
      }, {
        "__type": "Employee:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
        "Absence": [{
            "__type": "Absence:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
            "Timestamp": ["\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(1443736800000+0200)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"],
            "Type": "Vacation Leave"
          }, {
            "__type": "Absence:#Common.Entities.Integrated_Calendar",
            "Timestamp": ["\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(1443564000000+0200)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/", "\/Date(-62135596800000)\/"],
            "Type": "Working from Home"
          }
        ],
        "Details": {
          "__type": "User:#Common.Entities",
          "DisplayName": "Andrew"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Table HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead class="thin-border-bottom" staff-calendar-table-head></thead>
 <tbody staff-calendar-table-row></tbody>
 </table>
```

Directive Code:

```
  module.directive('staffCalendarTableRow', [function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'features/staff-calendar/partials/staff-calendar-table-row.html',
      controller: function($scope) {

      },
      controllerAs: 'StaffCalendarController'
    }
  }]);
```